# My program don't see spaces

Tags: java, android

I think my program is skipping spaces on `charAt`.

The morse code looks like `... .. --`. I want to show this code but I think that it skips space here:

```
if(mors.charAt(i)==' ') {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
String mors = info.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I just tried this on my computer and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
String mors = "... .. --.";
for (int i = 0; i < mors.length(); i++) {
    if (mors.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        System.out.println("Found space at " + i);
    }
}
```